# Log mysql queries to console

Tags: sails.js, waterline

Is there an equivalent to LOG_QUERIES=true from sails.js v0.12?
I'd like to be able to log my mysql queries to the console

Answer (score 1):

You can do a sails lift by using following command.

```
LOG_QUERIES=true sails lift
```

This is supported by `sails-mysql` adapter as queries are run by this adapter.